# From the hourly data create a time series of daily data

Tags: r, time-series

How can I convert hourly data into a daily data time series?

here's my code for the hourly data:

```
rainfall$V1 <- as.POSIXct(paste0(rainfall$V1), format = "%d%b%y:%H:%M")

rainfall <- tidyr::complete(rainfall, V1 = seq(as.POSIXct("1992-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1992-12-31 23:00:00"), by = 'hour'),  fill = list(V2 = 0))

rainfall_ts <- ts(rainfall$V2, start= c(1992,01,01),  frequency = 24*366)

head(rainfall)
```

[head(rainfall)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HE49.png)

V1 is the date(hourly)

V2 is the rainfall

Comment: Do you want to get the `sum` of 'V2' per day, then do `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(Date = as.Date(V1)) %>% summarise(V2 = sum(V2, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: the `fill = list(V2 = 0))` in the `tidyr` call won't populate NA or '' with 0?